# The execution of template action 'Response' is skipped: the client application is not waiting for a response from service

Tags: azure-logic-apps

When ever i try to run my logic app i get an error

> The execution of template action 'Response' is skipped: the client
>   application is not waiting for a response from service

[image: Logic-App]

[image: Image-2]

[image: Image-3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you created the trigger "When a HTTP request is received", so we need to request the url which generated in the trigger to trigger this logic app, if we click the "Run" button on azure portal, it will show the message you mentioned in your question. You can request the url in postman with the parameter "message" in json type, it will work fine(it will response the language in postman).

Comment: same applies for if you resend the run